# Reload a page in PHP and values of variable

Tags: php

I am trying to write a very simple PHP page to calculate the first 100 prime numbers. HTML consists of a very simple form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Numeri primi</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="get" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="nascosto">
<input type="submit" value="CALCOLA">
</form>

<?php

if (isset( $_REQUEST['nascosto']))
{
$cont = 0;

for ($num=2;$cont<100;$num++)
    {
    if (test_prime($num))
        {
        $cont++;
        echo $num." ";
        }
    }
}

function test_prime($n)
{

  if ($n===1)
      {
      return false;
      }
  else if($n === 2)
      {
      return true;
      }
else
  {
    for($x = 2; $x < $n; $x++)
        {
          if($n % $x === 0)
          {
           return false;
          }
    }

return true;  
  }
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

The hidden field "nascosto" is used to check when the page is reloaded after pressing on submit button.

The problem I found is that, when I reload the page pressing on reload button in browser (refresh), the list with prime numbers isn't deleted, but remains in the produced html (sorry for my bad english!).

I would like to delete the output produced by echo instruction when the page is manually reloaded or refreshed in browser. How can I do it?

Thanks so much in advance!
Giancarlo - Italy

Comment: What frontend technologies are you using? If it is an Single Page Application and you are sending an ajax request, of course, page content will remain the same,

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve], there's too much guessing involved in trying to figure out what you did. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve this by using Javascript. Please try the following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Numeri primi</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="get" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="nascosto">
<input type="submit" value="CALCOLA">
</form>

<?php

if (isset($_REQUEST['nascosto'])) {
    $cont = 0;

    echo '<div id="myDiv">';
    for ($num = 2; $cont < 100; $num++) {
        if (test_prime($num)) {
            $cont++;
            echo $num . " ";
        }
    }
    echo '</div>';
}

function test_prime($n) {

    if ($n === 1) {
        return false;
    } else if ($n === 2) {
        return true;
    } else {
        for ($x = 2; $x < $n; $x++) {
            if ($n % $x === 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}

?>

<script>
    if (window.performance) {
        console.info("window.performance works fine on this browser");
    }
    if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
        console.info( "This page is reloaded" );
        document.getElementById("myDiv").remove();
    } else {
        console.info( "This page is not reloaded");
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer... but it doesn't work. I edited my previous post in order to provide a more complete code. Thank for helping!

Comment: I updated my answer code according to your code, please try it now.